# Consultar y guardar información de un web service en mi BD

Tags: webservice

Desde un punto de vista general de programación, es correcto guardar información en mi base de datos que consulto a traves de un web service de otro sistema?
Tengo mi sistema que realiza una consulta a través de un web service de otro sistema externo, quiero saber si está bien consultar la información del webservice y tambien guardarla en mi base de datos, o lo correcto sería solamente consultarla.

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso todo va a depender que tan critico es la información y si en algún momento necesitas una comparación de la información consultada para realizar pagos por consulta a la otra aplicación.

si solamente es leer información para mostrar en otro sistema sin ningún tipo de implicación entiendo que no seria necesario que guardaras la información en tu base de datos

Answer (score 0):

He trabajado con WebServices y te comento las dos causas en las que debí de guardar información en mi base de datos y solo consultarla.

**Para guardar:**

Hice un sistema que sincronizaba/guardaba información con ayuda de WebServices. El tiempo de ejecución de un WebService es distinto dependiendo de las acciones que hagas, yo por ejemplo debía de **consultar e insertar** al rededor de 25 tablas y si realizaba este mismo proceso para verificar cada tabla era muy tardado.

Para esto, lo solucione en consultar una única vez la información y la guardaba en mi BD, para que la siguiente vez que debía de sincronizar ya no tuviera que ir a verificar por medio de WebServices, si no que lo hacía desde mi BD. **Aquí considerando que debía de almacenar unicamente ID de las tablas**.

En tiempo de ejecución esto si te sirve.

**Para consultar:**

Esto me sirvió para obtener solo información especifica de una cierta tabla, algo que no iba a interferir en mis procesos, por ejemplo para sacar información de un proveedor.

De igual forma, lo utilice para consultar información que yo sabía que iba a cambiar constantemente.

**Espero que te ayude esto, ya lo he aplicado y me ha funcionado muy bien**